# Is there a layout manager for PyQt / Qt similar to MigLayout?

Tags: java, python, qt

[MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is my layout manager of choice (In Java), and I can't find similar functionality in Qt (Tutorials in PyQt only consider QBoxLayout and QGridLayout). From the [Qt list of layout managers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), is there something similar to Mig?

Example from the [guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf) (Java):

```
panel.add(comp1)
panel.add(comp2, "span 2") // The component will span two cells.
panel.add(comp3, "wrap") // Wrap to next row
panel.add(comp4, "span")
```

[image]

I love how it's possible to expand an individual cell, instead of spacing them equally within a "grid". It allows you to build really complex UIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGridLayout does this. The `addItem` method has `rowSpan` and `columnSpan` parameters that allows the cell you're creating to span across, down, or both. It's very easy and works great.

ADDITION:

For inserting a widget, use addWidget. Note that there are two versions, and one of them allows for column and row spanning.

Comment: I can't add a normal `QPushButton` with addItem because it takes a `QLayoutItem` instead of a `QWidget`. The `addWidget` method has no span, only alignment.

Comment: Sorry about that. I skimmed the docs too quickly. There are two addWidget overloads. The second one allows for spanning.

Comment: I've found this [stack post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097030/qt-layout-relationship-between-qlayoutitem-and-qwidget). I'm trying to figure out how to "transform" a `QWidget` into a `QLayoutItem`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see as well. Thank you!!